# Clear cookie and force Login each time user visits site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, authentication, asp.net-identity

I have a web application built using asp.net mvc. I'm using the standard build in authentication - asp.net Identity (SignInManager & application cookie), although I've hooked this to MySQL back end.

As expected, when the user leaves my web application but returns to it in time before their session expires they can access the authorized pages on the site and when the session expires they are redirected to the log in page.

My question is, is it possible to force them to log in every time they return to the site after leaving it?  The scenario being, they closed their browser or navigated away from the site all together.

Appreciate the help guys!

Comment: When they close their browser it should clear a session cookie unless you've set IsPersistant to true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "issue" the authentication cookie as "session" cookie. Session cookies disappear when all instances of the same-brand/same-mode browser is closed. By "same-mode" I mean incognito and non-incognito.

Answer (score -1):

Keeping in mind your scenario, you can use following method.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("YourCookieValue", false); //second aurgument is persistent
```

you can set the `persistent` value to false so whenever a user closes his/her browser he/she will be logged out.